# How to add null value in where clause (comparison)

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here is my table called sample.

```
id  name    grade   sign
1   pinky   A       null
2   smita   B       sam
```

I want to add new record into sample table after checking name,grade and sign.If record not found for these combination,insert else not.

```
declare @count int
select @count = count(*) from sample where name = @name and grade= @grade and sign = @sign
-- @name,@grade and @sign are input para
if(@count = 0)
begin
-- insert 
end
```

Problem occur when I trying add first record that is pinky,'A' and null.It give count as zero and record get added.How to handle this?My table may have  null value or may not have null value.Depends.
I know comparison of null with null,always false.`(null= null)`

Hello friends,thanks for ur help.I tried following code.

```
select @count = count(*) from sample where name = @name and grade= @grade and  (sign = @sign OR (Sign IS NULL AND @Sign IS NULL))
```

But it does not worked.It gave me count as zero instead of 1.

I tried liked this also.I worked when I trying to add first record that pinky,A and null.Ithas shown me 1 as count.Prompt me to add further.

```
 select @count = count(*) from sample where name = @name and grade= @grade and  (@Sign IS NULL or sign = @sign)
```

but fail when I am trying to add new column having a value 'smita','B',null.It gave me one as count.But it is wrong.Record does not exist for these combination

Checked ur query once again @Mukund

```
select @count = count(*) from sample where name = @name and grade= @grade and  (sign = @sign OR (Sign IS NULL AND @Sign IS NULL)).
It gave me count as zero instead of 1 when I am trying to add 'pinky',A and null
```

Comment: `WHERE (sign = @sign OR (Sign IS NULL AND @Sign IS NULL))`

Comment: can you check my solution once? @Swati

Comment: i have added a fiddle to my answer, see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use if exists:

```
if not exists(
select * from sample where name = @name and grade= @grade and (sign = @sign or (sign is null and @sign is null))
)
    begin
      insert into sample(name,grade,sign) values (@name,@grade,@sign)
    end;
```

have a look at the example <kbd>**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e24b/12)**</kbd>

6 queries of insertion, with 2 of your records to show what happens in each case.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a few extra checks on `null`:

```
sign = @sign or (sign is null and @sign is null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it in this way.

```
select @count = count(*) 
from sample 
where name = @name 
and grade= @grade 
and isnull(sign,'') = @sign
```

what it will do, if there will be any value as null in column then it will replace it with '' and then will try to compare.

Comment: Think this should be `isnull(sign,'') = isnull(@sign, '')`

Comment: is it possible to have @sign as null. if yes then she can do it. Result would be same in both case.

Comment: According to the question it is possible for `@sign` to be null - and the result will not be the same. If `sign` is null and `@sign` is null, then you end up with `'' = null` which is null, i.e. not true. Whereas if you use `ISNULL(sign, '') = ISNULL(@sign, '')` and both `sign` and `@sign` are null then you end up with `'' = ''` which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is vulnerable to a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). In a multi-thread environment, there is a change (however unlikely) that in between retrieving the count of matching records and inserting the new record that another thread has inserted the same record.

The first step to safeguard against this is to add a unique constraint. If `(name, grade, sign)` should be unique, then they should be constrained as such:

```
ALTER TABLE sample 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_sample__Name_Grade_Sign UNIQUE (Name, Grade, Sign);
```

You should do this regardless of the method you choose to insert records. This integrates your logic with the database, and protects it from any inserts that may not come from the application layer, for example someone could just run a stand alone query of `INSERT Sample (Name, Grade, Sign) VALUES ('pinky', 'A', null)`, this circumnavigates your insert method that supposedly avoids duplicates.

To avoid running into the race condition and getting constraint violation errors, the best way I know of is to use `MERGE` with `HOLDLOCK`:

```
MERGE sample WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING (VALUES (@Name, @Grade, @Sign)) AS s (Name, Grade, Sign)
    ON s.name = t.Name
    AND s.Grade = t.Grade
    AND ISNULL(s.Sign, '') = ISNULL(t.Sign, '')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Name, Grade, Sign)
    VALUES (s.Name, s.Grade, s.Sign);
```